# Address of the last cell with data in current row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have an Excel worksheet where there is numeric data from column M onwards (to the right). I would need to calculate the average of the values in each row without referencing to anything other than the column M in absolute terms.

So, I would need `=AVERAGE({1}:{2})`
where `{1}` is something like `INDIRECT("M"&ROW())`.

The question is what should `{2}` be? The right end of the data shifts constantly, and the values are not unique. In addition, there are blank cells in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Average will ignore blank cells or cells that have text, so you can reliably just use:

```
=AVERAGE(M2:XFB2)
```

By putting this in row 2 and copying down it will change the row numbers.

If you really want to stop the references then you can use:

```
=AVERAGE(M2:INDEX(M2:XFB2,MATCH(1E+99,M2:XFB2)))
```

Which will set the last cell with a number as the extent.

[image]

Comment: IF 1E+99 was an actual possible number, or smaller than the values in the columns, would it still work? 
 I have in my head that it searching for the last column where the search value is larger, but that does not mean I am thinking about this right. 
 If I am thinking about this right would the following be appropriate? 
 `=AVERAGE(M2:INDEX(M2:XFB2,MATCH(MAX(M2:XFB2)+1,M2:XFB2)))`

Comment: @ForwardEd that should also work, just more typing as the Match is looking for where that number is >= to on column and less than the next.  So it would work.  But you are talking 4 characters(`1e99`) compared to 14 characters.  I am lazy and like 4 better.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure my thought process was right.  I thought there was a third argument to match that toggle approximate match versus exact.  But I did not know what the default was if it was omitted.  Then for the cherry on the cake I thought I was thinking about Vlookup.  So thought best to ask for clarification.  Thanks for clarifying!